# MVC Form returns null model back to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

View has a list of items, each with a checkbox.  Purpose of the form is to check the boxes then return the list to the db.  I expect to see the PickList model in the ViewModel populated with the hidden seedid and the checkbox values, but the form always submits with the PickList as null.

```
@model Inventory.ViewModels.ExtractionViewModel

<div class="col-md-4">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" form="pick-list-form">Update Pick List</button>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdatePickList", "Extraction", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "pick-list-form" }))
{
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Seed Reference
            </th>
            <th>Extracted?</th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model.PickList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ExtractionId)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.SeedId)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SeedId)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => item.IsExtracted)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}

View Model

public class ExtractionViewModel
{
    public ExtractionDTO Extraction{ get; set; }
    public List<PickListDTO> PickList { get; set; }
}

Pick list model

public class PickListDTO
{
    public int ExtractionId { get; set; }
    public int SeedId { get; set; }
    public bool IsExtracted { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why is the button to submit the form, outside of the form?

Comment: I wanted the submit button in a different place and the form="" is supposed to allow that.  It does submit, so I assume it works.

Comment: @G-Town - switching the foreach to a regular for loop did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Using `@Html.DisplayFor`may cause the model to be sent back as NULL.** You can use `@Html.TextBoxFor`.

And just to remind:

Use `HiddenFor` when you want to provide posted data that the user does not need to be aware of.

Use `DisplayFor` when you want to show records but not allow them to be editted.

Use `TextBoxFor` when you want to allow user input or allow the user to edit a field.

I hope it helps you!

Comment: But the checkbox should be posting data because it is an input. and technically the hidden is an input as well.  So are you saying the mere existence of the displayfors is nullifying the whole form?